# Data binding and types with Katalon Studio

Tags: katalon-studio

I am struggling in Katalon Studio with Data binding and types. I am using an Excel file to populate variables used in my test suite (through data biding). 
The issue I am facing is that some of my variables should be Boolean but Katalon interprets them as String.

According to [this article](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/bind-as-string.html#variable-binding-for-test-data-with-option-embind-to-test-case-as-stringem-disabled), I should be able to enforce data type but it does not seem to work. Note that I am using data binding and it is not the case in the article.

Have someone already faced the same kind of issue and solved it?

Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

@Yacine - Can you kindly provide snapshot of your test case where you're using the test data and also provide snapshot on how you implemented the Data Files? This will help me troubleshoot your case more further.

However, from whatever information you've given so far, I'm guessing that you've the checkbox Bind to test case as string checked. Can you try to uncheck it and give it another try?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unchecking that box has no impact. By using data binding, all test case variables become strings. I've tested this extensively. If I can get someone from Katalon to acknowledge it and put it in the documentation, I'd consider that a good first step:

https://forum.katalon.com/t/test-case-variable-types-and-data-binding/53956

https://github.com/katalon-studio/katalon-studio/issues/467